# Bolero (F# Blazor) Debugging

Tags: f#, bolero

Does someone know how to debug a Bolero project? In particular, is it possible (and how) to debug the client project using and IDE (VS or VS code) or directly in the browser (source mappings)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no ability to debug Bolero (Client side) in the browser that I'm aware of. I recommend using a console trace to watch your model and updates: [example](https://github.com/fsbolero/Bolero/blob/73246e6f61d04e0949270f0c72b3f1884fad6cc2/tests/Client/Main.fs#L211). Additionally I've been adding heavy logging for my Bolero project, I find that's often easier with functional code anyways.

You *may* be able to use the [Blazor debugging techniques](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-components/debug?view=aspnetcore-3.0) though I suspect the mappings won't translate back to F#.